# How to reverse a GROUP BY like table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Animal Count  Color
------ -----  -----
Dog      2     brown
Cat      4     black

Result 

Animal  Color
------  
Dog     brown
Dog     brown
Cat     black
Cat     black
Cat     black
Cat     black
```

Comment: Why? Can't you just select from the original table and e.g. filter by `Animal`?

Comment: @Luaan No actually its a table. I want to split it as shown above.

Comment: Tricky. I'm affraid this is not possible without having a helper table to cross apply against. A bad solution :) Why do you need to do that on the DB level? It really doesn't make much sense in a relational query.

Comment: @SubinJacob Check my answer, here is SQL Fiddle sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44c51/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve It with `Common Table Expression` in following:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
   Animal NVARCHAR(20),
   CountAnimals INT,
   Color NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('Dog', 2, 'brown'), ('Cat', 4, 'black');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Animal,CountAnimals,Color FROM #Test

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT  Animal,CountAnimals-1,Color

    FROM CTE
    WHERE CountAnimals >= 2
)
SELECT Animal,Color
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Animal DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

DROP TABLE #Test
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Animal  Color
 Dog    brown
 Dog    brown
 Cat    black
 Cat    black
 Cat    black
 Cat    black
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44c51/1)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to introduce an artificial table (or view) the_row_holder_table with row count>=max count in the initial table. Then just

```
select gr.Animal, gr.Color
from grouped gr 
join the_row_holder_table on gr.count<the_row_holder_table.row
```

UPDATE:
Suppose the the_row_holder_table has just one column `row` with values

```
row
-----
1
2
3
...
```

Then each row of the grouped table is connected (by gr.countcount rows of the the_row_holder_table table

Comment: can u explain in brief

Comment: Can I use recursive cte?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Animal varchar(100), Count INT, Color VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    ('Dog',2,'brown'),
    ('Cat',4,'black')
```

Using a recursive cte + cross apply. You can do this:

```
DECLARE @max INT=(SELECT MAX(Count) FROM @tbl);
;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < @max )
SELECT 
    t.Animal,
    t.Count,
    t.Color 
FROM 
    @tbl as t 
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT * FROM Nbrs WHERE Nbrs.n<=t.Count
    ) AS f
ORDER BY t.Animal DESC
```

**Output**

```
Dog 2   brown
Dog 2   brown
Cat 4   black
Cat 4   black
Cat 4   black
Cat 4   black
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ints table(ID int)
declare @animals table(animal varchar(20),[count] int,color varchar(20))
insert into @animals values ('Dog',      2     ,'brown'),('Cat',      4     ,'black')

declare @int int = 1
declare @maxInt int = (SELECT MAX([count]) from @animals)
while @int <= @maxInt 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        @ints
    VALUES
        (@int)

    SET @int = @int + 1
END


SELECT
    animal,
    color
FROM
    @animals a
    INNER JOIN @ints i ON i.ID <=a.[count]
ORDER BY
    animal ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH CTE AS (

SELECT animal,count,color FROM tes

UNION ALL 

SELECT  animal,count-1,color

FROM CTE
WHERE count > 1
 )

SELECT animal,color
FROM CTE
group by animal,color
```